# ESP32 (BLE scan in arduino) sometimes doesn't scan the BLE devices for about 12 to 25 minutes. Why?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am working on ESP32 in Arduino IDE to scan for some BLE devices which advertise few data all the time. I am only scanning Eddystone data and printing on serial continuously in 5sec of time gap. The BLE scan part works fine but, sometimes I have seen in my serial output logs, it doesn't scan the data at all. This happens for 12 to 25 minutes as of now. What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.